# Docker based runner to use private image to build

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-actions-runners

My self-hosted docker based runner already activated at GitHub organization level. Separately to perform `npm` build through our private docker image,  Trying with below workflow `yml` code.

```yaml
name: CI with Docker

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: docker-runner # This is our Self-hosted docker runner
    container:
      image: ubuntu:npm-1 # This is our private docker image.

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build
      run: npm install
```

It fails with `Error: docker: command not found` this is expected since my `docker-runner` image doesn't loaded with docker engine package.

With Self-hosted docker runner, How do i call a private docker image and perform the build? Some pointers to achieve would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: looks to me like docker isnt installed on your self hosted agent. You should install docker enginer on that host.

Comment: Yes, Docker package not installed in our self hosted docker agent.  So to get work my workflow to use `private docker image` i need to use my host machine as runner instead of docker agent as runner?

Comment: I think you should just install docker on your runner. And maybe also log it into your private registry. It looks to me, it wants to do the right thing, but it can't because docker engine isn't available.

Comment: Ok, will install `docker engine` on my `docker runner` and try.